# Use default values for attributes in child class in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a Person class in Python

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name='Sam', phone=456):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
```

and a teenager class which inherits from Person :

```
class Teenager(Person):
        def __init__(self, name, phone,website):
            super().__init__(name, phone)
            self.website = website
```

Is there a way to instantiate a Teenager object using default values from Person class for `name` and `phone` without declaring them again in `Teenarger` class ?

When I try :

```
teen = Teenager(website='www.example.com')
```

I got this error :

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'phone'
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code but I get still the same error

Comment: Inheritance aside, you can't have a non-default argument (`website`) follow default arguments (`name` and `phone`), so you can't have `Teenager`'s args be `name, phone, website` if you want `name` and `phone` to be optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Teenager(Person):
        def __init__(self, website, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.website = website

teen = Teenager(website='www.example.com')
# or just
teen = Teenager('www.example.com')
```